# forward declaration of boost::thread variable

Tags: c++, boost

can someone please tell me can we forward declare a boost::thread variable. 
boost::thread t(thread); starts a thread, but I want to declare it somewhere and to start it somewhere else.
Thanx in advance.

When I use

```
boost::thread t;
t=boost::thread (thread);

/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In copy constructor ‘boost::thread::thread(const boost::thread&)’:
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27: error: ‘boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:35: error: within this context
thr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
thr.cpp:20: note: synthesized method ‘boost::thread::thread(const boost::thread&)’ first required here 
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In member function ‘boost::thread& boost::thread::operator=(const boost::thread&)’:
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:28: error: ‘const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable& boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::operator=(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:35: error: within this context
thr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
thr.cpp:20: note: synthesized method ‘boost::thread& boost::thread::operator=(const boost::thread&)’ first required here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way to do that is to use `thread`'s [move semantics](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.move_assignment):

```
boost::thread t;  // Will be initialized to `Not-a-Thread`.

// Later...
t = boost::thread(your_callable);
// Now `your_callable()` runs inside a new thread that has been moved to `t`.
```

**EDIT:** From the error messages you posted, it seems that you can't use move semantics with your version of boost. If that's the case, I'm afraid you won't be able to initialize a `thread` instance and have it start later.

Comment: what do you mean by your callable? how it is different from your_function(as you wrote before editting)

Comment: @Shweta, a callable can also be an instance of a class whose `operator()` has been overloaded (sometimes called a [function object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B)). I made that change for completeness :)

Comment: What exactly is *not working*? :) Can you update your question with the code you tried, and the error message if you receive one?

Comment: Nothing so special in the code and it was working before I tried your method on it, sorry just to cross check it. But now its giving these errors:

Comment: can you elaborate "your callable" please. May be there is some problem with my usage of thread

Comment: Well, "your callable" is what you pass to `boost::thread`'s constructor, i.e. something called `thread` in your example. But there would be other error messages if it was not callable.

Comment: Then can you please tell me what is the problem here.

Comment: My version is 1.33.1. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Shweta, the latest release of boost is `1.45.0`. Consider updating :)